# How do I output more than 255 characters in an Excel cell using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer() in php?

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I am trying to output a few paragraphs of text in an Excel spreadsheet, but right now the text is truncated to display only 255 characters. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
$xls =& new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$sheet =& $xls->addWorksheet($name);

foreach ($rec as $field) {
    $rec = ($rec['data'] ? $rec['data'] : $rec);
    $sheet->write($row, $col++, $field);
}
```

Is there anything I can do to get all of the text, not just the 255 chars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [a note in the documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-worksheet.writestring.php#5294):

```
$workbook->setVersion(8); // Use Excel97/2000 Format
$worksheet->writeString(0, 0, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Nothing makes me feel dumber than the answer being in the documentation, but I just didn't look hard enough.