# Unable to generate Excel through PHP with fields having length more than 255 chars

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to generate Excel sheet using "write" function of "Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer" package through my PHP code. Text length of few fields are more than 255 which causes them to truncate. I had tried using "setVersion(8)" but it is causing a corrupt/blank Excel sheet.

Am I missing something [apart from using setVersion]? Can someone please help on this asap, it is getting critical in my Project.

Comment: Didn't this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850182/how-do-i-output-more-than-255-characters-in-an-excel-cell-using-spreadsheet-exce

Comment: No...I have tried it already. It is generating corrupt/blank excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the package you mentioned, and I am sorry I didn't find that need, but I was happy working with this library when I had to write excel documents:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Take a look if you like,
·_-